Understanding and using SAML with Keycloak in a multi-tenancy environment
I'm building a multi-tenancy system, the front-end being a SPA, currently in the process of testing out multiple IdPs. I anticipate some wild requirements regarding the authentication process and with Keycloak being as extensible as it is, it's currently my favourite. SSO is a big requirement, customers should be able to "bring their own AD".
From what I gathered, I have two main options to configure SSO via SAML:

Create a dedicated client for a specific SAML Provider. Not really an option as we plan to provide a single front-end for all tenants.As a backup option this might work if we host our client on multiple subdomains per tenant with different client configurations for each, but it's not preferred.

Add the tenants SSO providers as identity providers to Keycloak. This leads to all providers being visible to all users on the login screen, which is far from ideal. Is there a way to limit this to only show local login & social providers? If so, how would one login to their company IdP? Is there a way to parametrize the login screen dynamically, i.e. add ?tenant?tenant1 to the authorization request so that only the appropriate SSO provider will be shown?


I've played around with SAML support in https://logto.io/ before. Here you configure the SSO providers as external IdPs. Additionally you would add mail domains which will be matched when a user logs in to with their company mail address. No SSO provider is specifically shown on login screen, only after the user has submitted their mail address. Is something like this achievable with Keycloak?

For anyone interested:
I found phasetwo which offers a managed keycloak solution. They developed an extension (keycloak-orgs) that does exactly what was mentioned above: mail/SSO provider matching, managing organizations and linking those organizations to SSO providers.
